# iTextSharp VB.NET change the font of a Paragraph

Tags: vb.net, itext

I'm learning iTextsharp and is hard without good documentation.

**I want to change the font of one paragraph**

Reading from http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/81/iTextSharp-Working-with-Fonts and trying to move the code to VB.NEt

I have this

```vb
Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 72.0F, 72.0F, 72.0F, 72.0F)
Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("c:\\PDFSample.pdf", FileMode.Create))

BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false)
Font times = new Font(bfTimes, 12, Font.ITALIC, Color.RED)

pdfDoc.Open()
pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph("This is normal text"))
pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph("Now the text is times", times))
pdfDoc.Close()
```

but I get the error

> 'BaseFont' is a class type and cannot be used as expression

Comment: `Dim bfTimes As BaseFont = ...` and `times = new Font(bfTimes, 12, Font.ITALIC, Color.RED)`  Fonts are resources which should be disposed of when you are done with them to prevent leaks.

Comment: I suggest you follow the advice from that link you posted and use `FontFactory` instead

Comment: "I'm learning iTextsharp and is hard without good documentation." You are right, mikesdotnetting.com isn't good documentation. That website is 8 years old by the way. You should take a look at developers.itextpdf.com. Although most examples are in Java, the usage of the API is identical for C# or VB.NET.

Comment: @Plutonix  thanks I will try with the info and if I find the solution I will post the code

Comment: @JoshPart thanks for the tip

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Thanks I will research on the site

Comment: OK, If I use something like

`pdfDoc.Add((New Paragraph("Texto con tipo de letra Times New Roman de 11", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 11, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL))))`

is working

Now I want to set myFont so I can use as a parameter

`Dim myFont As String = "FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 40, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLDITALIC"

pdfDoc.Add((New Paragraph("My own font on the paragraph", FontFactory.GetFont(myFont))))` but the font remains the same of the default, is not the one I defined

Comment: I found the solution


`Dim BIGGREEN = New Font(FontFamily.COURIER, 28, Font.Bold, BaseColor.GREEN)

pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph("My text on big and green gont", BIGGREEN))`